# ASP.NET Routing, Simple issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the below:

```
    routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToPages", "{PageName}", "~/Page.aspx");

    routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToProducts", "products", "~/Products.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToProduct", "product/{ProductName}", "~/Products.aspx");
```

Of course as you might have guessed, I can never go to /products on my website because it will automatically redirect me to ~/Page.aspx.
Is there a way to fix this and allow routing to other "directories" while maintaining a dynamic page name on the root of my domain ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about subdirectories of 'product'?

Comment: No i'm talking about going to http://mydomain.com/products automatically takes me to ~/Page.aspx (first rule) since it considers /products as -> "{PageName}"

Comment: I understand now. I posted something to try below.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally write an HttpModule to handle this, but I would imagine that the rules should be first matching. Try this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToProducts", "products", "~/Products.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToPages", "{PageName}", "~/Page.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToProduct", "product/{ProductName}", "~/Products.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the routes in reverse order - most specific to lease specific. When redirecting to a route, it will search until it finds a match, then it stops.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToProduct", "product/{ProductName}", "~/Products.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToProducts", "products", "~/Products.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToPages", "{PageName}", "~/Page.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to flip the routes around

```
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToProducts", "products", "~/Products.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToProduct", "product/{ProductName}", "~/Products.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteToPages", "{PageName}", "~/Page.aspx");
```

- `/products` should got to `/products.aspx`
- `/product/foo` should got to `/products.aspx`
- `/foo` should got to `/pages.aspx`

routes are first come first serve. If it makes route 1, that's the one it takes. `{PageName}` matches everything so naturally it will take it first

Comment: We need more of the same answer on this question.

Comment: my answer is more complete than yours for one and I answered within about 2 seconds of the other answers.

Comment: The same information is there; yours is just more verbose. and I think you meant 2 minutes not 2 seconds.